# How to run joomla website with existing old database?

Tags: php, joomla

I have complete Database backup of previously created joomla website. but I don't know  Admin username and password. I have imported old database successfully and have edited the necessary details like user,password, db name in configuration.php but i am still getting this error:

Database Error: Unable to connect to the database:Could not connect to MySQL.

```
var $dbtype = 'mysql';
var $host = 'localhost';
var $user = 'root';
var $db = 'old_databasename';
var $dbprefix = 'jos_';
```

I want to make this joomla website run so is this possible or not?

Comment: It seems that new Joomla cannot connect your MySQL server. Check your db config in your `configuration.php` and your MySQL server settings.

Comment: but in configuration.php, there is not any db config ...I have added this....var $dbtype = 'mysql';
 ` var $host = 'localhost';
 var $user = 'root';
 var $db = 'old_databasename';
 var $dbprefix = 'jos_'; `

Comment: Please read the manual of Joomla and find how to config the database.

Comment: The following file is on the server or local ?,In server means please check whether the password is empty or not.

Comment: It is on local and password is empty.

Comment: You will need to have a password setting in the configuration even if it is blank. However the installation screens of joomla indicate that you must use a password though I'm not sure it is enforced.

Answer (score 0):

If you backed up database is from an older version of Joomla such as 1.5 and you are trying to use it for a Joomla 2.5 website, then it won't work, however I'm not sure if it will cause the error you have described in your question.

I'm not sure if you have purposely not added the password variable to your question, but please ensure you have it filled in in the config.php

For the time being, you don't need the Admin username and password. Your first task is to get the site working. Once you have done this, install a fresh copy of whatever Joomla version you used on your previous site, configure your admin details then do the following:

1. Open phpMyAdmin, go the the `#__users` table for the new site.
2. Copy all the details down for the admin account.
3. Go to the `#__users` table for the old site, and override all the details.
4. The go to the admin backend for the new site you created and try logging in with the username and password you chose for the new site.

However as said before, your first task is to prevent the MySQL error and get your old site working.

Hope this helps